# Internal Server Error apache issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've got a strange problem while trying to add pages to my website.

I'm actually trying to create a "test.php" in my directory, but when I try to access it, I've got

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, contact@mywebsite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My .htaccess looks like this :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well, the first look you should take _always_ is into the log files. Because that is where the server tells you what the problem is.

Comment: do what it says `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` to find out what the issue is.

Comment: Have you checked that the rewrite module is installed/activated?

Comment: @ZenCodeWebdesign If it is not, then why should that file cause an error?

Comment: The last stored logs are 3 month old in the directory I checked. How can I know where the logs are ?

Comment: @arkascha: Because then Apache would not know these directives …

Comment: @arkascha because it would be using a module that is not recognized so it would cause a server error. The condition `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ` is normally used so that if it's not enabled it won't bring down the server. But doesn't appear he's using that. Still the error may not be related, he needs to check his logs.

Comment: Okay I don't know if I checked the right file, but I can see this : 


        [Sat Mar 07 22:33:47 2015] [warn] UID of script "/home/krokoweb/public_html/test.php" is smaller than min_uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now according to your error you posted it appears to be like a ownership issue. chown your web directory from the command line and see what happens.

```
chown -R apache: /home/krokoweb/public_html/
```

Note I used the user "`apache`" as example. Use whatever your web user is for your files. e.g. `www-data`, `apache`, `httpd` etc

See how that works out.

Comment: Okay thank you for putting me in the right direction : my directory was owned by my apache user, but not my test.php. It now works perfectly ! But is there a way to automatically change these rights when I upload a file ?

Comment: Good deal. Not really, with the normal ssh/scp etc, it uploads as the user you are logged in with and that has permission to write to the directory. Some clients might be able to do it. I've never need it. My files are owned by my sftp user. But have a look at this http://superuser.com/a/696134

Comment: Oh yes, I'm stupid. I'm logged as root on FTP... So okay everything is clearer now, thank's a lot !